# What is wrong with my question, and how can I improve it?

Tags: support, specific-question

I am building a site with Pinax, and its standard Django URL for the admin interface is giving a 404 error. I looked at the URLs.py, expecting to see commented-out lines for the admin interface, and saw what looked to me like urlpatterns including the admin interface among the initial barrage of URLs.

Wanting to understand things better, I wrote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556181/oh-where-is-my-admin, trying to give details and appropriately ask what is going on.

The question has, at present, three downvotes, three close votes, and no comments indicating what was seen as problematic.

How can I change my question (or write another question) to more appropriately ask what else I need for my project's admin interface to be available at a standard URL?

Comment: immediate suggestion: pick a title that both describes your questions, and doesn't look like you're typing lines from a play.

Comment: And cut it down to a MCVE.

Comment: There is 2 questions in one : how to access admin ? How to change page title ? Those two topics don't seems related to each other. ---> too broad.

Comment: Cute titles on the main site rarely work, and it really sets the stage for the viewer coming into the question biased against the question from the start.  Unless the question is truly awesome, it usually doesn't end well.

Comment: You never actually ask a question, you have described what you are seeing, but not what you're actually trying to solve

Comment: That question looks off topic to me.  What programming language is it about?  Looks like you're trying to *manage* a website, not develop one.  Might be on topic for [webmasters.se], but definitely not for SO.  The close reason is bogus, I think.

Comment: With you on this @Sayse where is the question?, not sure how Ben75 get's two questions I don't even see one, it's just a description of the behaviour they are seeing nothing more. So to answer this question - Plenty!

Comment: N.B. After being told to get an MCVE, I posted http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324351/how-do-i-address-the-mvce-expectation-if-the-basic-point-of-my-question-is-to-he  questioning whether an MCVE should be expected for questions in quest of an MVCE. Maybe I can get help there.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First of all [check here how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

---

After this generic recommendation, IMHO you question should improve this points:

- **The title** must be **improved** (make it clear and descriptive).
- **Be specific** (people closed question as too broad, you must focus on your problem and make others understand it).
- Text parts must be **more readable** (use [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) / enumerations to highlight important parts).
- Show **less code** (only the problematic part) **but:**
- Provide an [**MVCE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- Add **stacktrace** and/or **error messages**. 
  *No excuses here; you **must** have some feedback from your code execution. **SHARE IT!!***
- From [Patrice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2417948/patrice): If the code is relevant: **remove the *for curious readers* part**. If the code isn't relevant: why force whoever answers you to check it?