# How do I address the MVCE expectation if the basic point of my question is to help me get an MVCE?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

Following on the heels of [my last question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324208/what-is-wrong-with-my-question-and-how-can-i-improve-it), I tried to learn from the feedback and, after abandoning a few approaches, I wrote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602268/in-pinax-how-can-i-make-two-omnipresent-when-logged-in-as-a-user-added-intege#37602268, asking for help for how to do something.

johnrsharp answered, "This [still](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37577622/3001761) doesn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

That is, strictly speaking, true. I see no coherent way to interpret my last Pinax question as containing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

*However*, it is also true that the entire point of my writing that question was to *obtain* a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. My question is not "Why does my PHP page corrupt the database if I enter Bobby Tables's first and last name?", or "Why does my Ajax application appear as a blank screen when viewed with IE8 or earlier?". It is, or is intended to be, a question like "Are there any subquadratic replacements to the bubble sort?" or "What are the performance characteristics for a factory versus prototype-based approach to creating objects in JavaScript?"

If my question were about how to pin down a behavior, then it may be part of my due diligence to find out how to duplicate the issue I am experiencing, then pinpoint the issue as far as I can, while still reliably reproducing the behavior.

**This is different, at least in that I have never seen the behavior that interests me.** I don't have any example of an observed behavior that I am trying to pin down, which seems a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example, and again, the point of my question was to *obtain* a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example, or something cognate to it.

Can the MCVE explanation be relaxed for questions which aren't about pinning down behavior that the OP has ever observed?

Comment: Essentially "give me the codez" questions aren't very welcome here. "Give us an MCVE" is the new "What have you tried?"

Comment: There is no requirement for a MCVE.  But an MCVE can help users replicate and understand your problem when you have a problem to replicate.  When you are asking "how do I", it is possible, but can be tricky.  [This answer and the answer it links too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224098/add-something-about-minimal-effort-questions-to-the-too-broad-close-reason/224104#224104) sums it up very nicely

Comment: Eh, MCVE may not be necessary here, but my sense is that whenever your primary question begins with "what are my options?", it's probably too broad. Also be aware your second question may attract the negative meta effect (not by me, but it does happen).

Comment: People are too quick to jump on the "We need an MCVE" bandwagon. Questions asking *how* to do something by nature do not have an example (barring mockups, other working examples, etc). MCVE only makes sense when there is an *issue*. Having said that (and not knowing what Pinax is), it looks like you have a few questions: How to add a page header, how to add (integer) widgets, how to add a save button, and how to save changes to objects. They don't below in one question. I would imagine seemingly simple operations like this would be present in the userguide/tutorial, no?

Comment: See [Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286757/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-demand-the-op-post-some-code)

Comment: Leaving aside the MCVE comment (which I disagree with), everyone who voted to close the question (myself included) cited the reason "too broad". Personally I think the lack of MVCE is not the issue - it's simply that the question is very broad and, IMHO, somewhat lacking in clarity (asking for "options", ambiguous requirements like "easily updated", "something comparable") and doesn't show any prior effort in terms of trying to find solutions.

Comment: As the commenter (good effort on my name): hello! An MCVE *isn't always* necessary, I mentioned it primarily because you'd asked the question once already and hadn't bothered doing anything as a result of the feedback you'd received (also note that you should edit the previous question rather than just open another). The questions you claim you intended yours to be like would also be too broad for SO.

Answer (score 14):

Your new question does not need an MVCE, but it asks how to do too many things. Notice that it was closed as Too Broad, not that it lacked example code. You need to break this down into a few things. Your question already starts breaking the task down into parts, actually:

- Add a header to a page (or maybe a global page header; I'm not totally sure from the question)
- Add two Integer widgets to the header
- Add a save button associated with the widgets
- Rig up the save button to update added fields to the User object

I'm not that familiar with Pinax, but from an HTML/CSS/JS perspective, these would all be separate tasks, each with its own bit of code. This is why it wasn't well received: it reads like a, "Gimme teh codez" (or alternatively, "Do my work for me") question. And to some degree it is, although I'm sure that's unintentional.

On the other hand, I may have a better idea where your frustration and difficulty come from. A quick Google for some of your problems gives me the impression there simply isn't all that much out there for you to find. Pinax's official docs are [here](http://pinaxproject.com/pinax/), but they look pretty sparse to me. It looks like the expectation is that you'll learn most things by looking at a prepackaged example. It's built off Django, so you might be able to leverage Django functionality.

As much as I hate to say it, you may not really be able to find enough help on it to get to the point where you can ask an on topic question on SO. If so, your best bet might be to contact the maintainers more directly. As great as Stack Exchange is with so much expertise, not every question can find a place here, and that's okay. [Pinax's website](http://pinaxproject.com/) lists a Slack chat where you might be able to ask. If you can get going a little bit with help from there, then you'll have a partially working example to go off of to ask future questions. If you do ask future questions about it, make sure they focus on a narrow piece of functionality that you're having a problem implementing, and make sure to document your efforts trying to implement it and how they failed.

I think you should also be careful about the nature of questions you ask about this technology. From what I can glean, Pinax appears to be a tool that's supposed to pretty much do everything for you out of the box. As such, you may find that some problems in it are *not* **programming** problems. I'm not going to categorically rule out the possibility that you may encounter coding problems, especially since I don't know the technology. But I advise you to be mindful of this concern and to try to make sure that the problems you ask about are on topic.

Good luck.